# Python script not working on Ubuntu, does on Windows

Tags: python, csv, ubuntu-12.04

I have two files in a directory. One is a .CSV file and other is a Python script. Python code looks like this:

```
from pyx import *
import csv
import re
import sys

def write():

    name = raw_input('Enter the name of .dat file: ') + '.dat'
    file = open(name, "w")
    for i in range(0, len(x_lista)-1):
        file.write(x_lista[i])
        file.write("  ")
        file.write(y_lista[i])
        file.write("\n")
    file.close()



def read_CSV(x_lista, y_lista): 
    currency = raw_input('Enter the name of input .CSV file: ') + '.CSV'
    #print currency
    with open(currency, 'rb') as f:
        reader = CSV.reader(f)
        lista = list(reader)

    print lista

    if(currency == 'Frank' or 'USD'):
        factor = 4
    else:
        factor = 3

    for i in range (3, len(lista)-factor):
        temp = (re.split(r'[";"]', (';'.join(lista[i]))))
        temp1 = temp[0]
        x_lista.append(temp1)
        temp1 = temp[1]
        y_lista.append(temp1)
    print x_lista, y_lista



x_lista = []
y_lista = []

read_CSV(x_lista, y_lista) 
write()
```

It takes what's in .CSV and by splitting/joining lists it produces a .DAT file consisting of two columns of data. Well... it does on Windows. However, when I try to compile it on Ubuntu I get this:

```
 Enter the name of input .CSV file: Euro
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "nwb.py", line 46, in <module>
        read_CSV(x_lista, y_lista) 
      File "nwb.py", line 22, in read_CSV
        with open(currency, 'rb') as f:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Euro.CSV'
```

What would be the solution?

Comment: Are you *sure* the Euro.CSV file is in the same folder as your python script?

Comment: ARGH! Ok, my fault! I haven't changed 'reader = CSV.reader(f)' to reader = csv.reader(f). Didn't spot that one, so I guess I wasn't sure! THX

Answer (score 2):

In Unix system file names are case sensitive.

For example: `Euro.CSV` and `Euro.csv` are different file names. Maybe the error is shown because of that

Comment: Tried that, nothing unfortunately